Why don't save 'Extension.SaveAs3' the step without new coordinate system?
I often get step-files. The coordinate system will never be the same. So I searched for solutions, that transform the main coordinate system into another. I found a good solution here on Stack Overflow

system Sub SaveToStep()
    Dim swApp                   As SldWorks.SldWorks
    Dim swModel                 As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swModelActivated        As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim swModelToExport         As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
    Dim strModelName            As String
    Dim nStatus                 As Long
    Dim nErrors                 As Long
    Dim nWarnings               As Long
    'Declare variables

    Dim OutputCoordSys As String
    Dim FileToExport As String
    Dim StepFile As String

    Set swApp = Application.SldWorks

    FileToExport = "C:\Users\mypath\mypart.SLDPRT"
    
    OutputCoordSys = "Koordinatensystem1"
    
    StepFile = Replace(FileToExport, ".SLDPRT", ".STEP")
    
    'Open
    Set swModel = swApp.OpenDoc6(FileToExport, 1, 0, "", nStatus, nWarnings)
        
    'Activate the model
    strModelName = swModel.GetTitle
    
    Set swModelActivated = swApp.ActivateDoc3(strModelName, False, swRebuildOnActivation_e.swUserDecision, nErrors)
    
    'Get the active model
    Set swModelToExport = swApp.ActiveDoc
    
    'Assign correct STEP
    swApp.SetUserPreferenceIntegerValue swUserPreferenceIntegerValue_e.swStepAP, 214
    
    'Set Export appearences option to true
    swApp.SetUserPreferenceToggle swUserPreferenceToggle_e.swStepExportAppearances, True

    'Assign Output coordinate system to use
    swApp.SetUserPreferenceStringValue swUserPreferenceStringValue_e.swExportOutputCoordinateSystem,
OutputCoordSys
    
    'Save the file as step
    swModelToExport.Extension.SaveAs3 StepFile, 0, 1, Nothing, Nothing, nErrors, nWarnings
End Sub 


I tried the code. The preferences will be changed correctly. I checked it by stopping before SaveAs3 in the program code and looking in the settings. But when I open the Step-File, the position of coordinate system is the old position.
When I save manually, the right (new) coordinate system is used in step-file.
Has someone an idea how I can solve this problem?

There are two different subsets of SetUserPreferenceString. One on the ISldWorks object and one on the IModelDocExtension object.  To set the coordinate system, I think you need to use the other one (as well as the correct enum) swModelToExport.Extension.SetUserPreferenceString swFileSaveAsCoordinateSystem, 0, OutputCoordSys  (the docs say this is obsolete but it may still function)

A lot of thanks bigcrazyal. Now it works. This is the solution.
